# Size of forms and its controls are smaller than usual

Tags: c#

When I add new form to my project, size of the Form and controls are really small that e.g. the text of button can not be read. But when I run the solution it is normal.This image shows the form before and after the execution.

Could you please help me to solve the problem
[image]

Comment: are you familiar with using the forms designer..? perhaps you need to investigate how the form controls are being sized have you looked at any of the .cs files that relate to the particular forms..?

Comment: Check the zoom level for designer window

Comment: Check the Form's AutoScaleMode1

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get what you mean about your answer